# Cannot obtain a trusted connection when hosting Jupyter Notebook on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am wanting to host Jupyter notebooks on my AWS instance and I am following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mxnet/latest/dg/setup-jupyter.html) tutorial. On step 2, I am configuring an SSL certificate as follows

`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout "cert.key" -out "cert.pem" -batch`

I am able to access the notebook successfully, but I get a warning that my connection is not secure

[image]

On the backend, the Jupyter notebook logs the following warning

`[W 19:53:29.080 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 10 ('127.0.0.1', 43680): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:777)`

Any ideas on what would be wrong with the SSL certificate?

EDIT

The reason that I am accessing the localhost is that I am launching the application as follows

`ssh -L 8157:127.0.0.1:8888 <username>@<instance> jupyter notebook`

The SSL cert is stored on the EC2 instance and the Jupyter notebook config can locate the certificate (Jupyter complains if it cannot find the certificate locally).

Comment: First off: `127.0.0.1` is your own localhost; not your AWS instance.

Second: Where are you storing your SSL certificate?

Comment: @TJBiddle please see my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a self-signed certificate. Those are not trusted by the browser. If you want a proper certificate, you should assign a domain to that IP and then get a certificate for that domain with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

But if you want to hide your service behind SSH, there is really no point in adding HTTPS on top of it. All your communication is already encrypted with SSH. You're not gaining much by using HTTPS here.

Comment: Then that error message does not make sense. It tells the user that https is not working. Instead is should say that the website is not trusted. I want encryption to a server that I personally trust.